# Why doesn't monad take `(M a -> M b)`?

Tags: monad

All apologies -- I'm still very much on the outside of Haskell looking in.

Why does the bind for a monad have this signature:

> M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b

and not

> M a -> (M a -> M b) -> M b

i.e. a function that takes `M a` instead of just `a`

`a` is available to the function in both, but the context that `M` provides is not available to the function in the 1st. Just the lifted value itself.

(If that's a silly question, just downvote me a lot & I'll delete it... like I say, still very much on the outside looking in)

Comment: It's not a silly question. But tell me: how do we *ever* get at the `a` if only the `M a` is available? Assume we have no other ways except for `bind` to access the thing “inside” the monad. The `bind` is exactly this “accessor”, and the more interesting question is why it returns a `M b` instead of just a `b`.

Comment: aha! OK I've been writing direct accessors (like Left/Right), but  making that a requirement would be a sort of 4th monadic rule.  I think I understand the M b part (admitting that I understand ***nothing*** about Haskell), because the action function needs to set up chaining in the monadic space. Otherwise, a) you'd always have to do bind + return and b) the action function might want to invoke M outside of b. For example, the bind function might want to call Left instead of Right, but (a -> b) wouldn't allow that. That's gotta be wrong, but I feel like I'm getting closer.

Comment: That's good! Actually, a function with the signature `(a → b) → M a → M b` exists as well : `fmap`. However, assume we want to write a filter that decides whether we include any element in the output. For example a List Monad: with `bind`, we can `return item` to keep, or the empty list `[]` to discard an item. With `fmap` we can do the same, but we would get a list of lists: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` might produce `[[], [2], [], [4]]` when filtering for even numbers. We need a `flatten` that outputs `[2, 4]` for `fmap` to be as general as `bind`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a hint: `a -> M b` is more general than `M a -> M b`, since you can do `a -> M a` any time with `return`.

Answer (score 5):

Let’s call functions that return a monadic value “actions”.

The type signature for `>>=` in `p >>= q` says that:

- Given a nullary action `p` that returns something of type `a`
- And given a unary action `q` that takes an `a` and returns something of type `b`
- You can chain them to get a nullary action that returns something of type `b`

It is worth remembering that `>>=` has a flipped version: `=<<`, that might be easier to understand visually—it corresponds to function application in a monad:

```
($)   :: (a ->   b) ->   a ->   b
(=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

Whereas `$` is application of a pure function to a pure argument:

```
succ $ 2 + 2
```

`=<<` is application of a side-effectful function to a side-effectful argument:

```
putStrLn =<< readLine
```

And you may have seen the Applicative operator `<$>` (an alias for `fmap`), which is for the other common case of pure functions with side-effecting arguments:

```
lines <$> readFile "input.txt"
```